# OCaml Error : Fatal error: exception Cmi_format.Error(_)

Tags: error-handling, ocaml

I'm using OCaml on my Windows device via Cygwin. I installed Opam as well, and also ran the command

```
opam pin add merlin --dev-repo
```

because after installing the most recent OCaml for Windows the compiler ocamlc wouldn't work and some Google searching offered this solution.

The error that I got when I first tried to run ocamlc was:

```
Error: C:\OCaml\lib/pervasives.cmi
is not a compiled interface for this version of OCaml.
It seems to be for an older version of OCaml.
```

However, now whenever I type "ocaml" in the terminal, rather than getting the interactive editor I get the fatal error message:

```
Fatal error: exception Cmi_format.Error(_)
```

Does anybody know what the problem might be? Thank you.

Comment: You have installed two different versions of OCaml which have no `cmi` file compatibitliy, and use `ocaml` of one version against the library of the other.   Probably ``eval `opam config env` `` may help, but I am not sure without enough details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installed two different versions of OCaml that weren't compatible.